# Routing API v8 Routing to multiple waypoints

Tags: here-api

What is the maximum number of waypoints you can have with the Routing API?

I am looking to have a starting location and then add up to 500 waypoints and have it optimize the route.

Is this possible with the Routing API?

Comment: Good question. If there is a limit it isn't documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only support GET method, **POST will allow more, but it is not (yet ) supported** currently support whatever URL length limits allow.. So something like 100+ waypoints ,But for optimising the route, there is a separate service which solves this.

Comment: What is the service for optimizing routes called?

Comment: Fleet Telematics Waypoints Sequence: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html


Matrix of Routes: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-matrix-of-routes.html


Large-Scale Matrix Routing: https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/index.html

Comment: Does the HERE Routing API v8 support POST now?